# Office 365 API SharePointClient | How To get listitems?

Tags: office365, visual-studio-cordova, sharepoint-online, office365-apps

I am developing a Office 365 Mobile App with Cordova in Visual Studio 2013.
So I am using the Client Libraries.

I can authenticate to SharePoint Online using the discoveryContext

```
discoveryContext.services(authContext.getAccessTokenFn('Microsoft.SharePoint'))
    .then((function (capabilities) {            
        capabilities.forEach(function (v, i, a) {
            var endpointUri = v.resourceId + "sites/APIWorkspace/_api";
            if (v.capability === 'MyFiles') {
                sharePointClient = new Microsoft.CoreServices.SharePointClient(
                    endpointUri,
                    authContext.getAccessTokenFn(v.resourceId)                        
                );                    
                console.log("Connected to Sharepoint");                 
            }                
        });
    }).bind(this), function (error) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    });
```

My Question is, how can I access the lists from SharePoint Online? Are there any documentations about sharepoint.js or the SharePointClient?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use files object to get the items. You can find SharePoint documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/common-file-tasks-client-library), there is not much JavaScript samples, it is in-process of getting updated. If you are adding O365 services through [**Add Connected services**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn771546.aspx#Office) then you can look into `services\office365\scripts\typings\sharepoint.d.ts` to find different API and can easily construct the API calls.

```
sharePointClient.files.getItems().fetch().then(function (result) {
    result.currentPage.forEach(function (item) {
        console.log(item.type + ' "' + item.name + '"');
    });
}, function (error) {
    console.log(error)
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.
Unfortunately I get an internal server error (500)
Here is the stringified error:
{"statusText":"Internal Server Error","status":500,"responseURL":"https://rippleapi.herokuapp.com/xhr_proxy?tinyhippos_apikey=ABC&tinyhippos_rurl=https%3A//*****-my.sharepoint.com/sites/APIWorkspace/_api/files%3F_%3D1418802479799","response":"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: serviceContext","responseType":"","responseXML":null,"responseText":"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: serviceContext","upload":

Comment: At the example I am connecting to a already existent site collection. (endpointUri is a string I built on my own)
When I change the argument to v.endpointUri I am connecting to my sharepoint.com/personal and not to sharepoint.com/sites/....
When I do that I get four items. But they are almost completly empty. Type and name are undefined (like almost everything)